# How to keep Form visible when binding data to it [sapui5]?

Tags: sapui5

I have this little project for documentation purposes. I want my Forms to enable the user to write new data, read already posted data and change existing data.
My problem are the following two:

1. When I use oForm.bindAggregation(...) my Forms aren't visible
2. When I use oForm.bindElement(...) the Forms are visible but no data is given...

I don't know why sapui5 behaves like this since I am rather new to it. But the binding with the Tabels and Lists work perfectly fine with Aggregation Binding.

Please help. Thank you in advance!

```
var oView = this.getView();
        oView.bindElement({
            path: "/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").newPath
        });

var oForm = this.byId("thStr");
var oFormItem = this.byId("strSession");

var sPath = oView.getBindingContext().getPath();
var newSes = sPath + "/zuSession";

oForm.bindAggregation("formContainers", {
    path: newSes,
    template: oFormItem
});
```

And for bindElement:

```
oForm.bindElement(newSes);
```

automatically created oData xml snippet of Z_SESSION:

```
    <EntityType Name="Z_SESSION" sap:content-version="1">
<Key><PropertyRef Name="SessionNr"/><PropertyRef Name="ThId"/></Key>
<Property Name="SessionNr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" 
MaxLength="2" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Nummer" 
sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" 
sap:filterable="false"/>
<...>
</EntityType>
```

XML snippet of Form:

```
<f:Form class="sapUiSmallMargin" visible="true" editable="true" 
id="thStr">
    <f:layout>
        <f:GridLayout/>
    </f:layout>
    <f:formContainers>
        <f:FormContainer id="strSession">
            <f:formElements>
                <f:FormElement label="Session">
                        <DatePicker id="sesDat" value="{path: 'Datum', 
                          type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Date'}">
                            <layoutData>                                                                     
                               <f:GridElementData hCells="2"/>                                                               
                            </layoutData>
                        </DatePicker>
                        <ComboBox id="sesV" placeholder="V" items="{/Z_VSet}" selectedKey="{V}">
                            <layoutData>                                                                     
                               <f:GridElementData hCells="1"/>                                                               
                            </layoutData>
                            <items>                                                                  
                               <core:Item text="{VKey} {Beschreibung}" key="{VKey}"/>
                            </items>
                        </ComboBox>
                  </f:FormElement>
            </f:formElements>
        </f:FormContainer>
    </f:formContainers>
</f:Form>
```

Comment: please add you data-model, the xml and a bit more controller code

Comment: i still don't get how your data-model looks like. You have a list of "zuSession" with the Properties  Datum, Beschreibung, and VKey right? Is there any "root" entity bound to the view? If you use bindAggregation, do you have multiple instance of "zuSession"?

Why do you provide the template in code and not via XMlL definition?

Comment: "zuSession" is the navigation property which leads from a therapy to it's session (Z_SESSION[Set]). Sorry, forgot to mention that... (the Navigation goes something like ".../MY_SERVICE_SRV/Z_THERAPY(ThId='123')/zuSession?$skip&$count&soOn). Right now I just want one session for one therapy in one Form. And I use it in the code and not in the XML because it seemed easier for a dynamical approach.

Comment: if you still need help rewrite your question. It is still not clear to me. Adding data-model "json-example" helps, the entire view(simplified - remove all non essential things) as well as the controller (simplified). and a brief description of want you want and what happend instead. I dont get if you want to display/create/update something etc.

Comment: I found out with Aggregation Binding the forms are visible when there is at least one Entry in my DB Table. I just don't understand why it behaves like that. For the JSONModel you are asking for: What does it help you with if I write a JSON manually based on how my ODATA model looks like? Then for my Controller: It is already pretty simplified, I put a simplified version into the first code snippet. And the XML is also already packed... What I wanted was to simply be able to edit my Forms, when they are not visible, I can't do that. Thank you for your help and time:)